# How can I hide if I was using nginx or apache2

Tags: nginx

I was able to hide version of nginx by "server_token  off;"
but I want to hide that whether I am using nginx or apache2.
how will I be able to do this ? 
any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this. You can modify the source of nginx and changing the server signature in the source, recompiling and installing from there.

Alternatively you can add a module called headers-more-nginx-module

This then allows you to modify the headers without recompiling each time you wish to change the headers.

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule#more_set_headers

Both of these do however require recompiling ngnx and reinstalling.